# Get a value from a key of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

ARRAY 1:

```
array(1) {
  ["en"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["em"]=> null
  }
}
```

ARRAY 2 VALUES:

```
array(15) {
  ["something"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["somekey1"]=>
    string(25) "value1"
    ["somekey2"]=>
    string(9) "value2"
    ["somekey3"]=>
    string(5) "value3"
    ["somekey4"]=>
    string(3) "value4"
  }
  ["en"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["em"]=>
    string(4) "RESULT"
```

Look at array on `["en"]["em"] = "RESULT"` from both arrays.

I want using `$array1` and `$array2` to intersecting a keys of array and get a result from `$array2`:

NOTE: On `Array1` can be more nested arrays, **ARRAY1** should find this keys on **ARRAY2**:

NOTE: I don't want to grab a data like `$array2["en"]["em"]`, only using custom functions. (for example: custom `array_intersect()`)

I have 2 arrays. Look at only keys. On Array1 there is `en,em` keys. I want these two keys to intersecting on Array2. When is intersecting with Array2, it will on Array2 get a value `en,em->RESULT`. I don't want a classical way to grab a data, just a COMPARE TWO ARRAYS and GET A VALUE.

I've tried intersecting, but this ONLY works if two arrays ARE SAME. So, I need to intersecting using nested recursive searching by key!

Example, I don't want:

```
$array2['en']['em'];

some_function_to_search_array_by_key(array $array2);
```

Example, that I WANT to:

```
Using function `array_intersect()` or some hardcoded sample.

get_result_by_two_arrays($array1, $array2);
```

Example of Result:

```
INPUT:

// search by arrays keys
$array1 = array('en' => 'em');

$result = get_result_by_two_arrays($array1, $array2);

RESULT:

$result = 
(string)RESULT;
```

Comment: so what have you tried so far

Comment: I've tried to grab a data from `array2` using `array_intersect()` but it's strings problem. I want grabbing a data from `array2` using compare keys and pick up a value from `array2`.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Brate, kad bi mi tebe razumeli šta ti hoćeš ;) Like @RocketHazmat said, output example would be nice.

Comment: But `$array1 = ['en' => ['em' => null]];` from top is not different from `$array1 = ['en' => 'em'];` in example.

Comment: True, but how to intersecting only by keys. Value on array1 should not to considering into array2. Just only keys to compare.

Comment: Can this (http://3v4l.org/UZiSV) be what you need?

Comment: Instead of `var_dump( get_result($array2, 'en', 'em') );` should be `var_dump( get_result($array2, $array1) );` because a data from array1  can be vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of what I think you want :

```
$array1 = ['en' => ['em' => null]];
$array2 = ['en' => ['em' => 'RESULT'], 'something' => ['somekey1' => 'somevalue1', 'somekey2' => 'somevalue2']];

function get_result_by_two_arrays(array $array1, array $array2) {
    if (!$array1) return;
    do {
        $key = current(array_keys($array1));
        $array1 = current($array1);
        if (!isset($array2[$key])) return;
        $array2 = $array2[$key];
    } while (is_array($array1));
    return $array2;
}

var_dump( get_result_by_two_arrays($array1, $array2) );
# string(6) "RESULT"
```

Comment: You are AWESOME! Thank you! Works! It's working as full array and on one array! GREAT SNIPPET!

Comment: I think this can be useful snippet! Thanks.